# No incrementa valor de variable

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de usar un ternario para validar si existe el valor de la variable `$row`.

Si EXISTE debe incrementar su valor en 1, y

Si NO EXISTE o es cero (0) se le asigne el valor de 1.

```
$row = 3;
$row = ($row) ? $row++ : 1;
echo $row;
```

Pero el operador de incremento `(++)` no está incrementando el valor, el `echo` me muestra 3.
Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Intenta con `++$row`

Comment: Haz lo que dice @alanfcm: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.increment.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de dos formas ya que es una asignación

```
$row = 3;
isset($row) ? $row++ : $row = 1;
echo $row;
```

O solo sumale 1

```
$row = 3;
$row = ($row) ? $row+1 : 1;
echo $row;
```